# Error https://datatables.net/tn/7 Datatable serverside processing

Tags: datatable

I am new to here and datatable.

I try to learn the implementation of datatable at server side processing.

I use the code from https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

my web page at http://testlearn.infinityfreeapp.com/

shows the below error

DataTables warning: table id=test1 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see https://datatables.net/tn/7

don't have enough knowledge to sort it out.

Also happy to share the server access (login details) if required.

(just send an email to manmadhang@outlook.com)

Any or all help welcome.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tech support helpdesk.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.